# Windows Forms button's ForeColor is not changing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `MDI Forms`. In my parent form I have a `ToolStrip` with buttons. Yesterday the I had to change the text from black (which I think was the default color since I didn't change it before) to gray. I can see the text in the Designer changing to gray, in the `MainForm.Designer.Cs` the code is :

```
this.btnClients.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
            this.btnClients.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.btnClients.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveBorder;
            this.btnClients.Image = global::ShoesUnlimitedAdmin.Properties.Resources.Clients;
            this.btnClients.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.btnClients.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.btnClients.Name = "btnClients";
            this.btnClients.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 49);
            this.btnClients.Text = "Clients";
            this.btnClients.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClients_Click);
```

And more exactly :

```
this.btnClients.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveBorder;
```

which is kind of gray (I tried with custom color as well but didn't work either). But when I start the application the text color stays black as it was before.

Comment: Are you changing the color property before, after, or inside the call to `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: In the ParentForm, in fact this was the whole idea - before I was changing the color of the pressed button to orange. Now I want to set the default color to gray and change the color of the pressed button to black. So yes - I change the color on `button_clicked` event.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Setting the `ForeColor` property works just fine for me. Although I don't recommend it.

Comment: @Cody Gray : I Also don't understand, that's why I post this question. In the designer view my foreColor is what I want it to be. When I start the application it turns back to default. But all this is described in my OP.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase: I cannot reproduce this problem. The code you posted in the question works perfectly fine when added to the `InitializeComponent` function and/or configured at design-time. Therefore, there is no way to help you. There is something else wrong, something you haven't told us about. Can you reproduce this in a new, empty project?

Comment: Well, the project is big enough to not be able to post all parts that may interfere with this issue. I saw this `this.myArrayElements[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;` and I thought that the problem with the ForeColor could be something like this. However I didn't find out where I can use this `UseVisualStyle..` property, nor I'm sure this will solve the problem. But yet thanks, it seems I'm gonna deal with it however I can.